How to find elements using selenium from a UI that uses frames
I am trying to automate a web UI that seems to be using frames. I am unable to locate some of the elements in that UI unlike other UI's that are developed without frame concept.
For eg: I am trying to click on a dropdown field. When I inspectd the field using "Firebug", I am see this html stack for this dropdown.
<frame border="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="5" name="body" noresize="" 
src="Pub_Docs/index.htm">
<body marginwidth="5" marginheight="0">
<form action="../dxnrequest.aspx?RequestName=TadiPost" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="TadiServer" value="TPASS"/>
<input type="hidden" name="TadiUrl" value="/testdx/curr_hols.call"/>
<div style="position: relative; left: 5px; top: 0px;">
<table width="100%" class="BKGND">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="position: relative; left: 4px; top: 1px;">
<table width="100%" class="PARAMS">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="TOP">
<table class="CLEAR">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="HEADER">Currency:</td>
<td>
<**select name="in_CUR_CODE" size="1">**
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td valign="TOP">
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>

Firebug is pointing to name="in_CUR_CODE for this dropdown.So I thought this would work.
ccy_dd_locator = "//form[@method='POST']//select[@name='in_CUR_CODE']"
CCY_DD_LOCATOR_VALUE_XPATH = (By.XPATH, 'ccy_dd_locator_value')
frame = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'body')))
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(CCY_DD_LOCATOR_VALUE_XPATH)).click()

But its not locating the dropdown and I am  getting "Timeout" exception.
Is there a different way in selenium to locate elements from an UI that are using frames?
This doesn't seem to work as with other UI's that are not using frames.
Any help in understanding this is much appreciated.

Edit the question and include the full exception message as text, properly formatted.

I think the locator is not correc for the frame. You should pass the ccy_dd_locator as xpath not string such as 'ccy_dd_locator_value'. Also css for the select can be like this. Check this code
frame = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'frame[src="Pub_Docs/index.htm"]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name='in_CUR_CODE']").click()


Thank you. I am getting the below exception
Stacktrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x0049E8E3+53283]
(No symbol) [0x00425041]
This is from the try block where I try to locate the dropdown
ccy_dd_locator = "//form[@method='POST']//select[@name='in_CUR_CODE']"
CCY_DD_LOCATOR_XPATH = (By.XPATH, ccy_dd_locator)
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(CCY_DD_LOCATOR_XPATH)).click()

updated check it again please

Its still not working. looks like I am able to switch to the frame, but the dropdown click is not working. I enclosed the DD click in an exception block and I got back the exception as  "GetHandleVerifier [0x0075E8E3+53283] (No symbol) [0x006E5041]". Although the test itself didn't fail, it does nothing.

I can only have more idea if I can see the whole log.

Ok, you mean the exception trace log?
